# Are regular expressions (1+ U 0*)* and (1 U 0)* different? if different, then what is the difference?

Tags: regex, regular-language

I am new to the field of regular expressions. Need to understand the difference between the two regular expressions (1<sup>+</sup> U 0*)* and (1 U 0)* considering that the alphabet for both is (1,0)

Comment: What regular expression syntax is that? Also, you should include the regex in the body of your question as well.

Comment: Those look like mathematical regular expressions, not programming regular expressions. math.stackexchange.com would probably be better.

Comment: Thanks Barmar for your comment, I'll move the question to that forum then.

Comment: @NishantKumar Cross-posting is generally frowned upon. I'd recommend you either flag your question for migration or delete this question before you re-post on math.se.

Comment: the <sup>+</sup> I guess only works in posts

Comment: I removed the other post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`(1 U 0)*` can also be read `(1 union 0) or (1+0) in formal languages theory` as `(1|0)* as a regular expression` meaning `1 or 0 epsilon times`

`(1+ U 0*)*` Doesn't not make sense but the idea is `(1|0)*`

If you need the difference between the [star](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kleene_star) and the plus it explains `*` also has `{E}` in its set which is the empty set which is different from 1<sup>+</sup>

Comment: I think `(1+ U 0*)*` is like the regex `(1+|0*)*` and I think it does match the same regular grammar as `(1|0)*`

Comment: Right that was the point but `+` in this case doesn't mean `regex +` it actually means `regex | `. But in formal language theory that would actually mean `(1 or or (0 epsilon times))epsilon times` or `regex (1 | | 0*)*` which again doesn't make sense

Comment: Oh I see what you mean. Well who knows what source the OP was working from.

Comment: to clarify, the + after one is superscript 1 (1^+). I'm not very sure how I write + in superscript here.

Comment: I updated my post. and you have to do 1<sup>+</sup> which I dunno works in comments

Comment: OK Jay, I edited my question accordingly. In that case, I hope the answer is still the same that these two regex's are same. Right?

Comment: Basically. It all ends up being the same because if you slice all the combinations you end up with the same `set` of results